# Why does SVD solve $\underset{U,V}{\min}\| A - UV^T\|_F^2$

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

I read [here](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/recommendation/collaborative/matrix) the following:

> You can solve the quadratic problem below through **Singular Value**
>   **Decomposition** (SVD) of the matrix $A$.
>
> \begin{align} \underset{U,V}{\min} \| A - UV^T\|_F^2 \end{align}

My question is **why?** Why exactly does the definition or computation of SVD of the matrix $A$ provide a solution to the problem above?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is similar to PCA.

Consider the objective function $$f(U,V) = \lVert A - UV^T\rVert_F^2,$$
and let $U$ be fixed with $U^TU = I$, then $V^T = U^TA$ minimizes $f$ by the projection theorem (here we project the columns $a_i$ of $A$ onto the space spanned by the columns of $U$). Substituting this for $V$ in $f$, then:

$f(U,A^TU) = \lVert A - UU^TA\rVert_F^2 = \mbox{Tr}[(A - UU^TA)^T(A - UU^TA)] = \lVert A \rVert_F^2 - \lVert U^TA\rVert_F^2.$

Thus, we formulate the following equivalent problem:
$$ \max_U \lVert U^TA\rVert_F^2 = \mbox{Tr}(U^TAA^TU),\qquad\text{subject to } U^TU = I.$$

The Lagrangian of this problem is:
$$ L(U,\Lambda) = \mbox{Tr}(U^T AA^T U) + \mbox{Tr}[\Lambda(I - U^TU)], $$
and the maximum is achieved at $U$ whenever:
$$ \nabla_U L(U,\Lambda) = 2AA^TU - 2U\Lambda = 2AV - 2U\Lambda = 0, $$
where $\Lambda$ is symmetric (and even diagonal, leading to the decomposition:
$$ A = U \Lambda V^T, $$
because $V^TV = I$, and is solved efficiently using the SVD.

EDIT: Improved my answer, because it had many mistakes. If someone finds more, let me know. I'm terrible at matrix calc.

Comment: +1 Thanks! - not sure I fully follow though, e.g. why do you say _"note that $U$ is orthogonal"_? (e.g. nothing in the problem statement per explicitly states that AFAICT). Also, if you don't mind me clarifying, what specific type of [duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(mathematics)) are you referring to?

Comment: Hey, my answer is really sloppy at the moment. Sorry about that, I will improve it as soon as I have some time.

Actually it is not really a dual problem, but rather an equivalent problem. Specifically, if you assume that $U^TU = I$ and fixed, then by the projection theorem you can find a matrix $V^T = U^TA$ that minimizes your objective function. Substituting that into the objective, then you  eventually arrive at something similar to $\lVert A \rVert_F - \lVert U^T A\rVert_F$, which yields the equivalent objective $\max_U \lVert U^T A \rVert_F$.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be reframed as "What is the matrix $B$ with rank $d$ that minimizes the Frobenius norm distance to $A$." The answer to this problem is given by the Eckart-Young-Mirsky theorem as
$$
B = U_k\Sigma_kV_k^*,
$$
where $A = U\Sigma V$ is the SVD of $A$ and $k$ subscript denotes truncation at the first $k$ columns of $U$ and $V$ and the $k\times k$ principal submatrix of $\Sigma$. This solution is unique iff $\sigma_k>\sigma_{k+1}$. A proof of this result and the very similar result for the 2-norm can be found on this Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation